# Slow Buckminster plugin resolution

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, buckminster

I am running a headless Buckminster build using ant that for some reason is taking 4+ hours to finish resolving all the plugins that need to be built.  There are about 350 plugins that need to be built, all of which are already on the local filesystem and are provided in a rmap file as "local" providers.

I have tried increasing the logging level to debug see what the build is busy doing for 4 hours but there is only log statements for the first 30 seconds or so, then the logging stops and the cpu usage goes up to about 100% until the resolution finally finishes after about 4 hours.

Does anyone have any further debugging tips or possible solutions to this slow process?

Comment: Could you post the log up to the point where it gets stuck (and a little bit beyond)?

Comment: This ended up getting resolved by moving to the latest version of buckminster.

Comment: Maybe post this as an answer yourself and close the question for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of Buckminster resolved this.  Some artifact resolution caching was added that greatly decreased the amount of time Buckminster spent resolving transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to dump the thread stack to trace which component is working and cost much resource.